# EDT violation on Codename One

Tags: codenameone, network-connection

**With this code:**

```
protected void second_ButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
  ConnectionRequest cn = new ConnectionRequest(); 

  cn.setUrl(theURLaddress);
  cn.setPost(false);  
  cn.addArgument("name", "this");

  NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(cn);
  cn.getResponseData();
}
```

**I keep getting the following:**

```
EDT violation detected!
com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$EDTViolation: EDT Violation Stack!
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:344)
EDT violation detected!
EDT violation detected!
EDT violation detected!
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.isNativeInputSupported(JavaSEPort.java:2459)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.isNativeInputSupported(Display.java:2306)
at com.codename1.ui.TextArea.setText(TextArea.java:406)
at com.codename1.ui.TextArea.<init>(TextArea.java:328)
at com.codename1.ui.TextArea.<init>(TextArea.java:257)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:771)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:727)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:692)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:536)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:788)
at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.handleErrorResponseCode(ConnectionRequest.java:680)
at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:379)
at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:261)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$EDTViolation: EDT Violation Stack!
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:344)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getImageWidth(JavaSEPort.java:3087)
at com.codename1.ui.Image.getWidth(Image.java:667)
at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getWidth(EncodedImage.java:413)
at com.codename1.ui.plaf.Border.getMinimumWidth(Border.java:200)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.calcPreferredSize(Container.java:1431)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.calcScrollSize(Component.java:579)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.getScrollDimension(Component.java:566)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.isScrollableY(Container.java:1495)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.isScrollable(Component.java:1413)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.setLayout(Container.java:246)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:205)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:189)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:180)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:952)
EDT violation detected!
...
```

What am I missing!!?

Answer (score 1):

Except for the lack of progress indication the code above looks fine.

It seems you are invoking `setText` off the EDT elsewhere but you cut the stack trace that pointed at that.

**Edited:**

From the revised stack trace it seems that this line is the important one:
at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.handleErrorResponseCode(ConnectionRequest.java:680)

You are getting a call to the handleErrorResponseCode which means the URL returned an error code. So we are showing you an error dialog. Yes it does violate the EDT (these exceptions are in the simulator to warn of potential bugs). You need to decide what to do on error response code and handle them appropriately either by deriving the connection request and overriding this method or by binding an error handler to the network manager or by invoking setFailSilently(true) on the connection request.

Comment: lack of progress is right. the above happens to be the **only** code edited in the StateMachine. added more to the stacktrace.

Comment: See my revised response